# Facebook Ad Targeting Search API: How to search target for education_statuses, relationship_statuses, interested_in and so on

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, search, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I want to search target for education_statuses, relationship_statuses, interested_in and so on to get their "id, name, audience_size"-like struct through the Ad Targeting Search API.

But I can't find how to search those search-tags in the Ad Targeting Search API page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-search/v2.7

I can only find them in the Ad Targeting Specs page:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/targeting-specs/v2.7

But the latter page isn't useful in my searching. Can anyone tell me how to search those tags? They seem to be lost in the Ad Targeting Search API page...

Answer (score 0):

These education_statuses, relationship_statuses, interested_in was not added under Facebook Marketing search API. So we have to use default key when we are Targeting audience which provided by Facebook Marketing API documentation.

[image: Here the screen shot and documentation link of predefined values.][Here the Facebook Marketing API documentation link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/buying-api/targeting/v2.8)